# Django Ajax-jQuery

Tags: ajax, django, jquery

Since I am relatively new to Ajax and jQuery, and having hard time doing this, I am posting this over here.

**Views.py**

```
if request.is_ajax():
    if request.method == "POST":
        chatroom_id = request.POST['chatroom_id']
else:
    chatroom_id =''

print chatroom_id
```

When I remove if `request.is_ajax()` condition , then it shows the error saying `Key 'chatroom_id' not found in <QueryDict: {u'reply': [u''], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'yIJct9O7WfyPnWmDosW9N5TEklRwoIHP']}>`

**Template.html**

```
{% for key, values in chat_data.items %}
    <div class="container-fluid" alt = {{key}}>
        <div class="row-fluid">
           <div class="span2">
             {{values.from}} <br/> {{values.init_query}}
            </div>

        <div class="span10 well">

            {% for k in values.chat %}

                    <label> Text : {{k.text}} </label> 
                    <label> {{k.date_time}} </label>

            {% endfor %}        

        <form action = "#" method = "POST" id = {{key}} class="chatroom">
           {% csrf_token %}
               {{ form.as_p }}

            <input type="submit" value = "Sent" class="btn btn-primary"> 
        </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Since, there will be many chats and correspondingly reply submit button and its key, I want that when I reply to a specific chat, it carries the key with itself and process the chat accordingly.

How can I achieve this using Django, jQuery and Ajax? Replies to be being sent should give via Ajax using jquery

I have written these jQuery lines of code, but they seem not to work. Where I am going wrog

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var form = $('#'+'{{key}}');

form.submit(function (event) {
event.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/dashboard",
    data : form.serialize(),
    success: function( response ) {
      console.log( response );
    }
});
return false;
```

});

Comment: have a look at: http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised

Comment: Its paid and moreover I want it to be done in Django(python)  not in rails.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the best free resource on the matter is Mike [Hibbert's video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jKSNciGr8kY) on using django with jquery to implement ajax.

Answer (score 0):

For the jQuery, you have a few mistakes, the post should look like this:

```
var form = $('#'+'{{key}}');

form.submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/dashboard",
        data : form.serialize(),
        success: function( response ) {
          console.log( response );
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Try that and tell me how it goes.

Comment: One thing I would like to tell that in `views.py` file, the condition `request.is_ajax()` isn't getting satisfied. Any idea why?

Comment: Is the error on the server or the browser, check the terminal to see if you have a 500 error,

Also i missed a comma, so copy the new code and try again

Comment: As I said, the condition `request.is_ajax()` isnt getting satisfied, so it goes straight into the `else`, thereby printing nothing.
Hence the terminal doesnt show any error.

Comment: Print the value of request.method

Comment: request.method is POST but request.is_ajax() is False.

Comment: @fm2munsh- I have edited the question. Kindly look into the same and provide our valuable suggestions

Comment: The error for chatroom_id is probably there because you don't have the hidden field for chatroom_id

Comment: Hey, I am able to do that with the hidden id. But what I want is that it should be done via jQuery using Ajax calls. The `is_ajax()` is false . Why?

Answer (score 0):

When you make an Ajax request with jQuery and Django with csrf you need to pass the token, this uses the jQuery cookie plugin from Django's docs https://raw.github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/v1.3.1/jquery.cookie.js :

```
/** Django's csrftoken ajax security & server failures */
App.ajax = (function () {

var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken'),
    host = document.location.host,
    protocol = document.location.protocol,
    sr_origin = '//' + host,
    origin = protocol + sr_origin;

return {

    'csrfSafeMethod': function (method) {
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    },

    'sameOrigin': function (url) {
        return (url === origin || url.slice(0, origin.length + 1) === origin + '/') || (url === sr_origin || url.slice(0, sr_origin.length + 1) === sr_origin + '/') || !(/^(\/\/|http:|https:).*/.test(url));
    },

    '$setup': function () {
        var scope = this;
        // TODO:  create server failure pages and alert mechanism
        $.ajaxSetup({
            statusCode: {
                401: function () {

                },
                403: function () {

                }
            },
            beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
                if (!(scope.csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && scope.sameOrigin(settings.url))) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                }
            }
        });

        return this;
    }
}());

$(document).ready(function(){
    App.ajax.$setup() 
    var $form = $('form');

    $form.on('submit' function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/dashboard',
            data: $form.serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                window.alert(response);
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Personally I would prefer to pass JSON, also what browser are you testing in? Look into these libraries:

https://raw.github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON/1.0.0/jquery.serializeJSON.js

https://raw.github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest/master/jQuery.XDomainRequest.js